# JIRA add definition of done to Kanban board

Tags: kanban, jira

I am using Kanban methodology for a software development project and I have successfully configured the board setting WIP limits, columns, statuses, swimlanes. However, I am struggling to insert somewhere a project level definition of done DoD and definition of ready DoR. What is the easiest way to insert those?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't directly embed this type of content into the board natively, and I'm not aware of any marketplace add-ons to help (but that doesn't mean one doesn't exist).

You can, however, edit the project's sidebar to include links to external resources. If you're using Confluence, for example, you may link to the Confluence space or the specific Confluence pages where the team documents their Definition of Ready and Definition of Done. If you aren't using Confluence, you can also link to documents in whatever document repository or wiki you are using - any URL can be included.